# Editing SystemUI Layout XMLs

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to modify my SystemUI so that the cellular signal status more resembles AOSP. I've replaced the necessary images, but now the layout isn't right.

Right now, it looks like this:
[image]
On AOSP, it looks like this:
[image]

The goal is to have the `E` icon and the data arrows actually overlap with the signal bar triangle.

I found the proper XML (`/res/layout/mobile_signal_group.xml`) in the SystemUI APK. This is the original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@id/mobile_slot" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingStart="@dimen/signal_cluster_padding"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:systemui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:id="@id/slot_no_sims" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:contentDescription="@string/accessibility_no_sims" />
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/data_combo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView android:id="@id/data_type" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <ImageView android:id="@id/data_inout" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@id/mobile_combo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@id/mobile_sim_icon" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <com.android.systemui.statusbar.AnimatedImageView android:theme="@style/DualToneLightTheme" android:id="@id/mobile_signal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" systemui:hasOverlappingRendering="false" />
            <com.android.systemui.statusbar.AnimatedImageView android:theme="@style/DualToneDarkTheme" android:id="@id/mobile_signal_dark" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:alpha="0.0" systemui:hasOverlappingRendering="false" />
            <ImageView android:id="@id/mobile_type" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:layout_gravity="end|bottom|center" android:id="@id/mobile_inout" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@id/mobile_combo_2stage" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:layout_gravity="bottom|center" android:id="@id/data_signal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:id="@id/data_rat_type" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:id="@id/voice_signal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView android:id="@id/voice_rat_type" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I modified it by taking `@id/data_type` and `@id/data_inout` and moving them to be right below `@id/mobile_sim_icon`:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@id/mobile_combo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:id="@id/mobile_sim_icon" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView android:id="@id/data_type" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView android:id="@id/data_inout" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <com.android.systemui.statusbar.AnimatedImageView android:theme="@style/DualToneLightTheme" android:id="@id/mobile_signal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" systemui:hasOverlappingRendering="false" />
    <com.android.systemui.statusbar.AnimatedImageView android:theme="@style/DualToneDarkTheme" android:id="@id/mobile_signal_dark" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:alpha="0.0" systemui:hasOverlappingRendering="false" />
    <ImageView android:id="@id/mobile_type" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView android:layout_gravity="end|bottom|center" android:id="@id/mobile_inout" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

(Abridged code snippet)

But when I do this and flash with the modified XML, SystemUI goes into a crash-start loop. It seems like any change I make to the XML causes this. I'm rather new to this, so maybe I'm missing a step.

So far I've tried:

- Moving `data-type`, `data-inout` into the other FrameLayout
- Moving the whole LinearLayout into the FrameLayout
- Wrapping the `data_combo` LinearLayout around the `mobile_combo` FrameLayout

All result in SystemUI getting stuck in the crash loop.

Is there anything else I can try?

Device:

- LG V20 T-Mobile (H918)
- Android 7.0

Comment: My guess is that you've inadvertently removed a view that `SignalClusterView` or its AOSP 7 equivalent is using. Is `@id/mobile_combo_2stage` still in place underneath? Can you post the logcat?

Comment: @MichaelDodd I should have specified; the second code snippet is just the relevant section, not the whole XML. I can't post a logcat, annoyingly, because ADB doesn't work when SystemUI is in the loop.

Comment: Is `@id/data_combo` referenced anywhere in the code? If you've moved `@id/data_inout` and `@id/data_type` into `@id/mobile_combo`, it could be that the .java file is still searching for those views as a child of `data_combo`. Try re-instating `@id/data_combo` as a blank `LinearLayout` and see if that fixes things.

Comment: @MichaelDodd I tried that too. Took out just the two elements and the inner FrameLayout, but it failed both times.

Comment: Do a search for `R.id.data_combo`. It could be that `findViewById()` is being called directly on that view, and thus returning `null` for the two ImageViews.

Comment: @MichaelDodd sorry, but how do I do that? Would an option be to keep those elements in there and also copy them to the new location, but set the originals' visibility to invisible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134973/discussion-between-michael-dodd-and-zacharee1).

Comment: @MichaelDodd I figured it out! For whatever reason, the XMLs were partially compiled. I had to use APKTool to decompile the APK, make the edits, recompile and then copy the META-INF folder back in. The data arrows are in the wrong place, but at least now I can fix it. Your answer was what made it work (the wrapping it all in one). Could you post it so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134973/discussion-between-michael-dodd-and-zacharee1), the SystemUI is crashing due to a NullPointerException when you move `@id/data_type` and `@id/data_inout` outside of `@id/data_combo`. This is because `findViewbyId()` is being called against `R.id.data_combo`, and so is looking for a direct descendant of `@id/data_combo`.

As you don't have access to the Java sources, one workaround is to wrap `@id/data_combo` around `@id/mobile_combo` so that `@id/data_type` and `@id/data_inout` remain direct descendants of `@id/data_combo`. For example:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@id/data_combo" ... > 
    <FrameLayout android:id="@id/mobile_combo" ... > 
        ... 
    </FrameLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```